# Getting website metadata (Excel VBA/Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba

I am trying to get information of stock code from below website using excel vba
https://www.screener.in/company/KRISHANA/

I went through network tab and found out the code was in under peers node
https://www.screener.in/api/company/13611040/peers/

below is the code which I've written in excel vba, the html page has no information on the code

Note: I dont want to duplicate this thread, I tried searching everywhere, if its not possible in vba,
can we achieve this in python.

```
URLS = "https://www.screener.in/company/KRISHANA/" 
Set xhr = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", URLS, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
            If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
                Set Doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
                Doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End If
        End With
        DoEvents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url is always the same and you only need to change the warehouse id, you can get the id in the following way. This is without intercepting any errors and only shows the basic mechanism.

```
Sub getDataWarehouseId()

    Const url As String = "https://www.screener.in/company/KRISHANA/"
    Dim doc As Object
    
    Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        
        If .Status = 200 Then
            doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            MsgBox doc.getElementByID("company-info").getAttribute("data-warehouse-id")
        Else
            MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the native web import:

1. Go to Data > From web
2. paste "https://www.screener.in/api/company/13611040/peers/"
3. Click on "Table0"
4. Click on "load"

Comment: I need to find this link "https://www.screener.in/api/company/13611040/peers/" programmatically instead of manual copy-pasting it

Comment: Record a macro while performing the import

Comment: assuming the company name is the one you want to variabilize you'll need to start on https://www.screener.in/company/KRISHANA/, find your way trough the html tags until you find the ID. Once you have this script you can just feed it the alternative company name and the table will be loaded.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've gone through the HTML response text, and no ID information exists over there. that is the reason, I am trying to go for that link. if there is any solution, it would be greatly helpful. btw, appreciate your responses.